# Use Unix Executable File to Run Shell Script and MPKG File

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I have 2 shell scripts and 2 mpkg installer, I am trying to use an unix excitable file to run them all. here is the script I have, but it always has error message "No such file or directory" ?

```
#!/bin/sh
# Find the absolute script current path
path=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

sudo sh $path/join.sh
sudo sh $path/join2.sh

#/usr/sbin/installer -dumplog -verbose -pkg $path/“esetv8.mpkg" -target /
#/usr/sbin/installer -dumplog -verbose -pkg $path/“sccm.mpkg” -target /


exit 0
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Works fine here, you sure the files exist? You should be more careful and add a check to see if they exist in the first place, something like: `[ -f "${path}/join.sh" ] && sudo sh "${path}/join.sh"`. Note that if the dir contains a space your version will fail, add quotes in that case.

Comment: Add an `echo $path` and verify that it doesn't contain spaces and other special characters.

Comment: thanks, ShellFish. you are right. my dir contains 2 spaces. that's why it failed :)

Comment: Cool, let me write up an answer so people won't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: also, I have another question, do you know why every time I run the script, first it listed all the folder names in current script directory? thanks!

Comment: No, try to comment out the `sh` commands, maybe one of those contains an `ls` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common issue when handling variables containing paths of directories and files is the presence of special characters such as spaces. To handle those correctly, you should always quote the variables, using double quotes. Better code would therefor be:

```
sudo sh "$path/join.sh"
sudo sh "$path/join2.sh"
```

It is also advised to wrap the variables using curly braces, this can also help to avoid unwanted issues. Resulting in following code:

```
sudo sh "${path}/join.sh"
sudo sh "${path}/join2.sh"
```

While this should work, it's also appropriate to mention that it's advised to check whether the files actually exist before executing them. Checking a file for existence can be done using `-f` and checking execute permission using `-x`. The proper code is therefor:

```
[ -f "${path}/join.sh" ] && [ -x "${path}/join.sh" ] && sudo sh "${path}/join.sh"
[ -f "${path}/join2.sh" ] && [ -x "${path}/join2.sh" ] && sudo sh "${path}/join2.sh"
```

Note that if you have a bunch of these, you'd be better off executing them using a for loop. Note also that `-f` becomes redundant when checking `-x` so better code would be:

```
[ -x "${path}/join.sh" ] && sudo sh "${path}/join.sh"
[ -x "${path}/join2.sh" ] && sudo sh "${path}/join2.sh"
```